# Extracting car-ferry routes with osm2po

Tags: routing, osm2po

I am building a routable network from OpenStreetMap using osm2po (v5.0.0). I would like to include ferry routes, but limit them to car ferries only.

I am using the following config (excerpt):

```
wtr.flagList = car, bike, foot, rail, ferry, poly
wtr.finalMask = car|ferry

wtr.tag.route.ferry =             2,   1, 10,  ferry

wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car|ferry

wtr.deny.access.no = car|bike|foot|rail|ferry
wtr.deny.vehicle.no = car|bike|ferry
wtr.deny.access.foot = ferry
wtr.deny.motor[car|_vehicle].no = car|ferry
wtr.deny.motor[_vehicle|car] = car|ferry
```

However, I keep getting pedestrian-only ferries. The problem is that often there are no other tags other than `route=ferry` by which I could filter (deny) them. Example:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/312631040

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Simply leave the default config untouched and un-comment this line:

```
wtr.tag.route.ferry=2,1,10,ferry
```

Background: Ferries are not necessarily *car*-ferries in OSM.
So the only chance to filter them is given by

```
wtr.allow.motor[car|_vehicle].[yes|destination] = car
```

which is already activated in the default config

Comment: Yes that works. My fault was to include `ferry` in the finalMask, giving me practically all ferries.